# Passing arrays to UDF; UBound

Tags: vba, excel

It's quite frustrating that I already seem to be doing something wrong in the first line of my first VBA project. In essence my project has already been stalled because I can't figure out why this works:

```
Function TestF(Values As Variant, Dates As Variant)
    TestF = Values(2)
End Function
```

But this does:

```
Function TestF(Values As Variant, Dates As Variant)
    TestF = UBound(Values)
End Function
```

(I just want to see that `UBound` works. So, I removed everything from the project that is not related.)

Where `Values` and `Dates` are each supposed to be a 1-dimensional array. (Or ranges? Or is that the issue?)

How do I fix the first bit of code?

I Googled and I Googled, but I haven't found my answer.

The (Excel) 'error' is get is `#VALUE!` from `=testf(A2:A10,B2:B10)`, where the ranges are like:

`-1000  31-Dec-13
-10 31-Dec-14
30  13-Mar-15
1200    17-Mar-15
-40 30-Jun-15
1300    30-Sep-16
1200    31-Oct-17
1250    30-Nov-18
1500    31-Dec-18`

Comment: You need to tell us the exact error you encounter and you need to show the origin of `Values`, preferably in a format we can reproduce.

Comment: Done. I hope you can easily spot my (thinking or otherwise) error!

Comment: @Keepthesemind what is the expected result ? what should be the value when you enter these `Range`s ?

Comment: @ShaiRado Well, 8 or 9 or something thereabouts.

Comment: @Keepthesemind what is `Function TestF` suppose to do ? count the number of dates in a range ? number of positive values in column A in a range ? what exactly ? this will allow us to understand better and give you the best answer

Comment: @ShaiRado In the second case it is supposed to return the number of elements in the first range minus 1. So 8. I'm interested to know why UBound in this case doesn't do that, and how I can get it to work.

Comment: A Range is not an array and doesn't have a `Ubound`. You could just use the `Count` property if you are always passing a range.

Comment: @Keepthesemind see my answer below the first case. I will let you think a little about the second case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your passing of array to UDF is your understanding about array and ranges. In general, ranges are presented as a two dimensional array even when they are with single row or column.

To make your code work, try the "Double Transpose Trick" which is pretty much the following:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim k As Variant

    k = Range("A2:F2")
    Debug.Print k(1)

    With WorksheetFunction
        k = .Transpose(.Transpose(k))
        Debug.Print k(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

The code above will hopefully result as an error in the `Debug.Print k(1)` part. This is because `k` is a two-dimensional array, although it is on one row only:

[image]

Comment this part or change it to `Debug.Print k(1, 1)` and continue with the `.Transpose` It will change your array to a single dimension and it will be working.

Thus, if you want your non-working formula to work, this is a possible way to do it:

```
Public Function TestFormula(myValues As Variant) As String

    Dim myArr As Variant

    With WorksheetFunction
        myArr = .Transpose(.Transpose(myValues))
        TestFormula = myArr(UBound(myArr))
    End With

End Function
```

**Some important notes:** the "Double Transpose Trick" works on one row ranges, when these should be transfered to array. If you are having a one column range, use "Single Transpose":

```
myArr = .Transpose(myValues)
```

With more than 1 column or 1 row, do not use transpose as it cannot be mapped to  a 1 dimensional array.

Furthermore, if you pass a range of once cell, it will not work. But you will find some way to go around it.

As mentioned by @cyboashu in the comments, the `myArr()` array would take values up to column 65536, because the `Transpose()` is made this way, probably for compatibility reasons with Excel 2003. To make a bigger array - [Put entire column (each value in column) in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268383/put-entire-column-each-value-in-column-in-an-array)

Comment: Thanks. This works. On that array/range thing: after the double-transpose trick, has it now become a 'true' array? Or only something that looks like it?

Comment: @Keepthesemind - it is a true one dimensional array.

Comment: Re your note. As it happens, _both_ single and double transpose work. :)

Comment: Just make sure you never pass something like A:A i.e. once your parameter rows exceed 65536 you are in for all type of nasty surprises. :)

Comment: @cyboashu - good comment, did you know it before or did you find it by checking it now?

Comment: 65536 is the known pain in the back limitation of Excels' Transpose. :) What makes it more fun is that Excel will silently truncate your array. No error thrown, at least at the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the right parameters to your **UDF**.

Both parameters are `Range`.

```
Function TestF(Rng1 As Range, DatesRng As Range) As Long

    Dim C As Range
    Dim x As Long

    For Each C In Rng1
        If Trim(C.Value) <> "" Then ' make sure there isn't a blank cell in the middle of your Range
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next C
    TestF = x - 1

End Function
```

If you don't have empty cells in the middle of your `Range`, then the following code will be sufficient:

```
Function TestF(Rng1 As Range, DatesRng As Range) As Long

    Dim C As Range
    TestF = Rng1.Cells.Count - 1

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted:

```
TestF=Values(Ubound(Values))
```

also, you should declare what your function is suppose to return, like

```
Function TestF(Values As Variant, Dates As Variant) as String
```