# VBA, Array range error, subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Hi  I am trying to make my array more dynamic to include all file paths in column G. However I have trouble doing that as I am getting `subscript out of range` whenever I try something like `arrayFilePaths = Range("G4:G5")` or any solution from here, [Put entire column (each value in column) in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268383/put-entire-column-each-value-in-column-in-an-array)

I get `type mismatch` or `subscript out of range` on the `OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))` line.

My code:

```
Sub main()

        Dim arrayFilePaths() As Variant
        Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

        arrayFilePaths = Array(Range("G4"), Range("G5"))

        Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))
        Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(arrayFilePaths)
            numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

            Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
            OK = sourceDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(arrayIndex))
            Debug.Print "SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

            numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

            OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
            Debug.Print "PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

            OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, arrayFilePaths(0))
            Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

            Set sourceDoc = Nothing
        Next arrayIndex

        Set primaryDoc = Nothing
        app.Exit
        Set app = Nothing
        MsgBox "DONE"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Add `.Value` so vba does not try to put the range itself, but the values in the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner , still getting same error, this is my new line `arrayFilePaths = Range("G4:G5").Value`

Comment: @ScottCraner without a `Set` keyword, it's always the class' default property if no member is specified :)

Comment: you get the error on that line or another?

Comment: with setting the array with `arrayFilePaths = Range("G4:G5").Value` the first location is probably `1` not `0`

Comment: `arrayFilePaths(0)` is non existent.  Take a look, in the `Locals` window, and you will see.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Got that, but I have found that unless I specifically state `.Value` when assigning the values to an array it errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner but `arrayFilePaths = Range("G4:G5").Value` produces a 2-dimensional array so the first element is actually `arrayFilePaths(1, 1)` or you need to transpose it.

Comment: @Peh, are you saying I need to switch it to arrayFilePaths from 0 to 1,1. ?

Comment: @excelguy if you use `arrayFilePaths = Range("G4:G5").Value` then yes. It is like `arrayFilePaths(row, column)` but since there is only one column `G` the second parameter is always `1`. So first item is `(1, 1)` second is `(2, 1)` …

Comment: @Pᴇʜ , so maybe a loop is needed then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use an array I am now using a collection to make things a bit easier. Also I moved the save file outside of our loop so that we aren't saving the file every time that we insert into it.

The pathway to your primary document, aka the one that you will insert into, has been set at index 1. The for each cell in range loop will add pathways to the files that you want to insert into that primary document starting at index 2.

Also I modified the error messaging a bit (tell you what index it is failing at)

```
Sub main()

    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

    Dim FilePaths As Collection
    Set FilePaths = New Collection

    FilePaths.Add "PRIMARY DOC PATHWAY HERE"

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("G4:G5")
        FilePaths.Add cell.Value
    Next cell

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(FilePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For colIndex = 2 To FilePaths.Count
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(FilePaths(colIndex))
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "(" & colIndex & ") PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next colIndex

    OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, FilePaths(1))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks  1) but how do I save it now? As it doesnt open, maybe a `saveas` would work?  2) Can I just add paths to column G and it will pick them up?  Of course I would have to manually extend G4:GX .

Comment: script is still saving outside of the loop, look towards bottom of the code. you can do a lastRow search to create a dynamic range.

Comment: Yes but the pdf is no longer saving, its just doing the combining but cant see the results.

Comment: it works for me. make sure that your replace FilePaths.Add "PRIMARY DOC PATHWAY HERE" with your actual primary doc file pathway. or make it first in your range that adds to filePaths collection and delete that line

Comment: Great it works. The nice part about it I can perhaps put a new /blank pdf in 'PRIMARY DOC PATHWAY HERE' , that way the original pdfs are not over ridden.